# cscope: Generate only one symbol using #ifdef

Tags: cscope

I have C source code which have lots of #ifdef ANSI macro.

For example,

```
#ifdef ANSI
int test
(
int a
)
#else
int test(a)
int a;
#endif
```

So If I use cscope+vim with the above source code to navigate test(), 
it always displays the same two symbols.(So I must choose one of two same symbol names.
It is very annoying)

Is it possible for cscope to generate only one symbol(Only generate symbol in #ifdef ANSI) ?

Comment: This is indeed a very good question.